# Binary Search Tree - to Make a dictionary

Tags: c++, c, binary-tree

I wanted to make a dictionary using BST but I did not have any Idea how to store them in the tree

```
struct node
   {
    char word[50];
    char meaning[256];
    struct node *left, *right;
   };
```

I started like that but I dont know which words to put in the left and which on the right...

Comment: Is this homework? If not, use `std::map<std::string, std::string>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a binary tree, you should use something like a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). BSTs are really more for "greater/less-than" relationships, which would be hard to map with words. With suffix trees your nodes are characters and branches eventually lead to leaves representing an actual word.

Comment: Also, don't use trees of any kind, just use a hash map! Always!

Comment: How is it difficult to map to words? I think lexicographical ordering works just fine.

Comment: @Brian Gordon: And when you want to get the dictionary in sorted order..?

Comment: Yeah, hashmaps (or even skiplists) are very much valid data structures to use. I figure, if he's looking for a tree implementation for a dictionary, this one might be more suitable than a BST. I'm simply suggesting an alternative tree structure, not necessarily discounting other data structure types.

Comment: @Manny, I think BST can also be suitable, because we can properly compare the keys of a dict, then store them in a BST. Am I right?

Comment: @Alcott A BST will certainly be suitable as long as there's a well-defined method for comparing two strings. It really depends on how you plan on using it. A suffix tree/trie may also save you space if you have to store similar strings like CAT and CAB.

Answer (score 2):

Which words to put left and which to put right would still follow the basic rules of a BST: All nodes to the left of a given root are guaranteed to be less than that root's value, and all nodes to the right of a given root are guaranteed to be greater than or equal to that root's value.

Apply that same principle to your dictionary. I don't know if you're using C or C++, but if you're using C++, I would recommend making a "Word" struct, and overloading it's equality operators. Then in your "node" struct, just have a Word, a left Node, and a right Node.

A BST is not the best choice of a data structure for a dictionary though. I would look into different types of maps and hashing.

Comment: yes but if i make the first word the root, which means the word which starts with A, then the tree will become unbalanced.

Comment: Well, that's just how a BST works. If you have already sorted data which you're feeding into a BST, then you're just making a glorified Linked List. I would suggest using a HashMap.

Comment: Ok just a simple question it is let me say "fair" to use for example the 13th character as a root?

Comment: If you absolutely need to use a BST, then I would randomly add the dictionary words. But yes, it would be fair to pick a random element of the array to start with. Normally though, you feed data into a BST as it comes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the words that are lexicograpically smaller than the word in the current node go left, the rest goes right. Use `<` to do the comparison on C++'s `std::string`, `strcmp` for C-style strings (NUL-terminated `char` arrays).

Comment: Ok but it is sorted and what should I make the root element, it is the first word then the tree will become unbalanced?

Comment: Who says the tree needs to be balanced?  As you add words to the tree, it will become unbalanced by nature.  You can later rebalance it with different techniques if you'd like, but having the tree be unbalanced to begin with isn't an error condition.

Comment: In the case that the dictionary you're using is sorted before insertion, you're going to end up having a linear search O(N) instead of O(log(N)), essentially negating any benefit of the BST. Granted, its a homework assignment, so efficiency isn't the biggest deal, but its worth knowing. If you're interested in balanced trees, look into 2-3 trees/Red-Black Trees. But that is above and beyond your actual assignment.